# Batch file CF Login

Tags: batch-file, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a batch file to login to CF and below is my snippet.
When the CF API endpoint is set, the cmd prompt asks for "userID" and expects user input. I have saved the userID and Password but still, I was not logged in successfully using the batch job.

```
@echo off
echo %time%
cf login -a https://api.cf.orc.sql.dummy.com
timeout 5 > NUL
set "User ID=%M547898%"
timeout 5 > NUL
set "Password=%Pass1234%"
timeout 5 > NUL
set "Org=%2%"
timeout 5 > NUL
set "Space=%2%"
```

Can anyone please help here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you move the login command to the end of the script, after you get the variables?

Comment: My requirement is, first we should enter the login then it will ask for credentials to enter. this is the scenario which I want to try.

Comment: are you trying to log in to gcloud instances?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to login to CF.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is more than a year old post, try this way, it will work.

cf login -a https://api.cf.orc.sql.dummy.com -u M547898 -p Pass1234 -o ORG_NAME -s SPACE_NAME